# Do I have any disadvantages playing CS:GO on Linux?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, linux

I started to play CS:GO once a week with my friends. Since I have a powerful developer laptop running Linux, I use it for these weekly meetings.

Assuming we are on the exact same system, do I have any direct disadvantages if I play on Linux compared to Windows? Like maybe the sound is worse or the hit boxes are different?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct disavantages. It's pretty much the same, even though I'd say I have better graphic performance on Windows than on linux. This also depends on the Linux driver you're using I suppose.

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossOver_(software)) can save your life, if you're missing things like DirectX. With this you have about zero disadvantages compared to Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

Assuming your drivers are updated your experience will be identical to those playing on Windows. In my experience I got about ~30 FPS more in Windows 10 than Xubuntu 14.04, but that was due to drivers not difference in game. I've also noticed more screen tearing in linux, but again this is due to drivers not the fault of the game itself.

Comment: But naturally DirectX doesn't work on Linux, so it is probably OpenGL, which I believe to be not the same level of performance.